Is $\omega_1$ the $\omega_1$th limit ordinal?
Let $\phi:\mathbf{Ord}\to\mathbf{Ord}$ be the function that gives $\phi(\alpha)$ be the $\alpha$-th limit ordinal. My question is for what $\kappa$ do we get $\phi(\kappa)=\omega_1$? My guess is $\kappa=\omega_1$. Namely since if $\alpha, \beta$ are consequective countable limit ordinals then $\alpha+\omega=\beta$. And adding $\omega$ many $\omega$s to a limit ordinal would not change whether the resulting limit ordinal is countable or not. Similarly my intuition tells me the same should hold true for any countable limit ordinal. Finally I also believe that $\phi(\alpha)=\alpha *\omega$(or perhaps its $\omega *\alpha$?) Regardless neither should be giving $\omega_1$ unless one is in and of itself $\omega_1$.

But $\omega*\omega_1=\omega_1$. More generally, you should prove by induction that $\phi(\alpha)=\omega*\alpha$.

(if you want $\phi(0)=0$)

No need to go to such extra-galactic heights as $\omega_1$ for this, as the basement-dwelling minuscule ordinal ${\omega}^{\omega}$ has this property, namely, an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ is the $\alpha$'th limit ordinal. But if you want the $\omega_1$'th limit ordinal, then that is easily seen to be $\omega_1.$

$\omega_1$ is indeed the $\omega_1$th limit ordinal.
For let $\alpha$ be the $\omega_1$th limit ordinal; then clearly, $\alpha \geq \omega_1$, since $\omega_1$ is the $\omega_1$th ordinal, and the $\beta$th limit ordinal is at least $\beta$ by induction.
Conversely, there is a family of $\omega_1$ limit ordinals less than $\omega_1$; namely, for each $\beta < \omega_1$, the ordinal $\omega_0 \times (\beta + 1)$ is a limit ordinal less than $\omega_1$, as it is countable. This demonstrates that $\omega_1 \geq \alpha$.
